# C# Взаимодействие с таблицами и облачными таблицами

Tags: c#, таблицы, txt

Подскажите можно ли получить каким-то образом значения из ячеек Яндекс Таблицы(или какого-то аналога) или же придётся после каждого изменения облачной таблицы, всем пользователям программы скачивать таблицу и класть в некое общее для них пространство(сервер), чтобы программа ссылалась на него?

Есть таблица более чем на 2000 строк, которая будет условно раз в неделю редактироваться, другими людьми и передаваться для работы другим людям.
в N-ом количестве столбцов этой таблицы необходимы все значения строк занести в некий элемент(ListBox/ComboBox и т.п.) из которого пользователь будет выбирать значение, в соответствии с другими значениями, и добавлять в свой файл.

Вроде как можно через Yandex API SDK залезть на диск и скачать Таблицу.
Если это реально, то возможно ли сделать некую проверку на версионность таблицы, при каждом запуске программы или по нажатию кнопки, если новая скачать и перенести в каталог.

Comment: Если реально сделать, скиньте ссылочки на почитать, что-то об этом

Comment: Можно для хранения данных о таблице использовать систему контроля версий, например git. Он вам и diff покажет и всю историю изменений запомнит. Правда это валидно только для текстовых файлов, но саму таблицу можно и в CSV хранить, это как раз текстовый файл.

Comment: Спасибо. Я как-то про Git забыл. Тогда такой вопрос. Скажем некая организация/человек, делают туже злосчастную таблицу. Выкладывает на своём ресурсе - сайте. Можно ли как-то будет автоматизировать загрузку с его ресурса или ему придётся также подгружать в GIT?

Comment: На этот вопрос у меня нет ответа.

Comment: Спасибо. Буду думать буду посмотреть.